# Appcelerator Studio - iOS navigation icons not showing up properly positioned

Tags: ios, navigation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm developing an iOS app using the new Appcelerator Studio.

If I compile my app with the 3.5.1 SDK I get this result (this is the right result, the thing I want):

[image]

If I compile my app with the 4.0.0 or with the 4.0.1 this is the result:

[image]

*I consider the second one absolutely not acceptable*.

Is there any workaround?

Quite incredibly, in the context of my app this problem is related to another one (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19215) that's solved in 4.1.1 SDK (but if I compile for something different than 3.5.1. ... )

Comment: have you tried setting a fixed with to all the buttons added?

Comment: They have a fixed width... I suspect this is an "ancient" Titanium bug, maybe solved in 3.5.1 and unsolved again after (https://gist.github.com/artanisdesign/8127588)